# Ionic cordova resources --splash Error

Tags: cordova, ionic3

> × Generating platform resources - failed! Error: encountered bad
>   status code (400) for https://res.ionic.io/api/v1/transform body:
>   {"Error":"source image 1280x1920 too small for
>   Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png, requires at least 2048x1536 source
>   file"}
>       at Response.res.on (C:\Users\newuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\lib\cordova\resources.js:148:32)
>       at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
>       at Response.emit (events.js:208:7)
>       at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

Comment: u need splash screen image size 2732 * 2732 and then try to upload

Answer (score 0):

Your image (1280x1920) is too small for Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png
It requires at least 2048x1536px.
Try upload a bigger image

See [Ionic Cordova Resources](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/resources/)